# Elixir - Map Replacing particular key values alone

Tags: elixir

I have an Elixir list of map in which I want to replace some values

```rb
map = [
  %{id: 1, users: [%{m_value: 2, n_value: 2}]},
  %{id: 2, users: [%{m_value: 4, n_value: 5}]},
  %{id: 3, users: [%{m_value: 3, n_value: 4}]}
]
```

In this map I want to replace all the values of `m_value` and `n_value` alone.

#### Example

I want to multiply all the `m_value` by 2 and all the n_value by 3

So my final output will be:

```rb
map = [
  %{id: 1, users: [%{m_value: 4, n_value: 6}]},
  %{id: 2, users: [%{m_value: 8, n_value: 15}]},
  %{id: 3, users: [%{m_value: 6, n_value: 12}]}
]
```

Do you have suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One **cannot replace** anything in everything in Elixir (with some very rare restrictions, like process dictionary, but this is definitely out of scope here.)

**Everything** in Elixir is immutable. Any code that looks like “updating” map, *simply produces a new map*.

One might go with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
for %{users: [%{m_value: mv, n_value: nv}]} = m <- map,
  do: %{ m | users: [%{m_value: mv * 2, n_value: nv * 3}]} 
#⇒ [
#  %{id: 1, users: [%{m_value: 4, n_value: 6}]},
#  %{id: 2, users: [%{m_value: 8, n_value: 15}]},
#  %{id: 3, users: [%{m_value: 6, n_value: 12}]}]
```

Comment: This only works if there is just one element in `users`. For a list implementation, another nested for is required.

Comment: @JonasDellinger indeed, there are many limits of using this answer as is.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your valid `map` is as follows:

```rb
map = [
  %{id: 1, users: [%{m_value: 2, n_value: 2}]},
  %{id: 2, users: [%{m_value: 4, n_value: 5}]},
  %{id: 3, users: [%{m_value: 6, n_value: 12}]}
]
```

*please note this is a List of Maps*

Then, you could try an [`update_in`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) when iterating through the elements in the list:

```rb
Enum.map(
  map, 
  fn el -> 
    el
    |> update_in([:users, Access.all(), :m_value], fn val -> val * 2 end) 
    |> update_in([:users, Access.all(), :n_value], fn val -> val * 3 end) 
  end
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: _Sidenote:_ I’d consider mentioning that “update” in `update_in` is a very confusing fake name since it does not update anything, it produces a new object with modified content in a handy way. Also, `& &1*2` and `& &1*3` look fancier and shorter than anonymous functions :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with all of that. I wasn't sure how much "non-updating" aspect of `update_in` is a problem in case of this questions, but I agree this should be explained to make requester aware of it. I've deliberately decided not to go with capture operator to make the code a little bit easier to understand (I've assumed the level of experience of requester). In terms of your solution, though @mudasobwa - can I ask you for expanding on your choice of `for` over `Enum.map`? Is there any performance impact here, or is it a personal choice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Jonas Dellinger noted in the comment to my answer, comprehension is way more flexible, when it comes to inplace filtering, nested enumerating etc. It is easier to modify accordingly to more restrictive rules and it is more succinct, after all :)

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer @mudasobwa. I'll try to apply comprehension a little bit more often and see where it fits better. Really appreciate your comment!